# Oracle client 12c , if i can't find uninstallation file, can i install 19c client on same server?

Tags: oracle-12c, installation, sap

I have a server that has oracle 12 client installed but now have an application that references the same server that needs oracle client 19c installed in order to work with the  service.
I cannot seem to find the uninstall file on the server and wondering if i can install 19c in addition as only one workgroup has a 19c database and needs the 19c client

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what operating system you're using.
It is perfectly possible to have multiple Oracle clients installed on the same machine under Linux.

> ... now have an application that **references the same server** that needs oracle client 19c installed in order to work with the service.

By "same server", I assume you mean same Database [Service].
If so, what version of the *database* are you running?  I can see that a 19 database would accept connections from a 12 client but I think you might have trouble getting a 12 database to be "forward compatible" with connections coming from a 19 client!